# Why the Drag and Drop of files does not work in .Net Maui for the MacCatalyst platform. Specifically the DragOver and Drop event?

Tags: drag-and-drop, maui, mac-catalyst

I have a page of a .Net Maui application that contains several Frame type controls inside a FlexLayout to which I have activated the Drop gesture. Following xaml code:

```
<FlexLayout Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,0,10" Direction="Row" Wrap="Wrap" >
   <Frame Padding="0" Margin="5,0,0,5" HeightRequest="120" CornerRadius="10" WidthRequest="200" BackgroundColor="#046EB7" HasShadow="False">
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="5">
        <Label FontFamily="FA_Free_Solid" FontSize="40" TextColor="White" Text="{x:Static fontHelpers:FA_Free_Solid.LockOpen}" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        <Label Text="Unprotect document" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="White" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
        </StackLayout>
        <Frame.GestureRecognizers>                   
            <DropGestureRecognizer AllowDrop="True" DragOver="DropGestureRecognizer_DragOver" Drop="DropGestureRecognizer_Drop"/>
        </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
   </Frame>
   <Frame ...
</FlexLayout>
```

The code behind the xaml:

```
void DropGestureRecognizer_DragOver(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DragEventArgs e)
{
   e.AcceptedOperation = DataPackageOperation.Copy;
}

void DropGestureRecognizer_Drop(System.Object sender, Microsoft.Maui.Controls.DropEventArgs e)
{
   var data = e.Data.Properties;
}
```

When running the application in MacCatalyst and trying to drag and drop a file into the Frame. The **DropGestureRecognizer_DragOver** and **DropGestureRecognizer_Drop** events are never called. I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

The events are expected to be called when dragging or dropping a file on top of the Frame.

Comment: https://vladislavantonyuk.github.io/articles/Drag-and-Drop-any-content-to-a-.NET-MAUI-application/

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Hans Passant I have tried the project from the suggested article from Vladislav Antonyuk and it happens that the drag and drop sometimes works and sometimes not. The SessionDidUpdate method of the UIDropInteractionDelegate is not always called when the action is executed. My question would be if there is some issue with the .Net Maui Drag and Drop API that makes it not work in MacCatalyst?

Comment: This could be a potential issue for the `DragOver` and `Drop` event on Mac platform, consider logging it on Github:https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues.